# Some design guidance please regarding wp7 listbox and data binding

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm porting an Android app to wp7 and I'm trying to do things the .net way, and I'm beginning to get my head wrapped around data binding, but I am lost when it comes to a few things.

My classes consist of the following:

- PickLeaf - the data representation of each item in the list
- PickLeafModel - the data representation of a collection of PickLeaf objects
- PickLeafCell - the user control for each item in the list
- PickLeafListView - derived version of ListBox
- PickLeafPage - the page that contains the list view and instantiates some of the controller objects and threads
- IPickLeafListener - an interface that the PickLeafPage implements and allows it to get notified when certain things occur regarding to the PickLeafCell (tap, context menu opened, scroll window changed)

Currently I am adding the PickLeafCell controls dynamically to PickLeafListView.Items, which kind of goes around data binding and perhaps is leading to some of the bugs I am seeing (such as updating it while its being scrolled causes scroll window to go berserk).

QUESTION: If I change it so that the PickLeafModel can be used as a DataSource, how do I pass the IPickLeafListener and PickLeaf references to the PickLeafCell using data binding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand your architecture, but I try.

First of all, bind your data to `ListBox`

`listBox.ItemsSource = PickLeafModel;`

Your `ListBox` should looks like:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ...>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <my:PickLeafCell DataContext={Binding} TapEvent="Tap" .../>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Two main thing happen here: `PickLeafCell` `DataContext` is bind to your data for each list item. And you subscribe to your `PickLeafCell` custom events.

When some event happens in `PickLeafCell` control, it raised custom event to which your main page is subscribed

```
 public class PickLeafCell...
 {
      public delegate void TapEventEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
      public event TapEventEventHandler TapEvent;

      protected virtual void OnTap(EventArgs e) 
      {
           if (TapEvent != null)
                TapEvent(this, e);
      }
```

This is your C# main page code-behind where you have event handlers:

```
 private Tap(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var item = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as PickLeaf;
 }
```

And in `PickLeafCell` control you have `DataContext` already set to your `PickLeaf`, so you can easy bind to fields

```
 <TextBlock Text={Binding SomeFieldOfPickLeaf} />
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to bind between the PickLeaf and the PickLeafCell. But how do I register the PickLeafPage for events coming from the PickLeafCell?

Comment: How do I bind the PickLeafCell events to the PickLeafPage event handlers? How do I do it such that they are connected as soon as possible once the list box is populated?

Comment: `TapEvent="Tap"` above. It's like when you subscribe to a `Button` `Click` event when `Button` inside `ListBoxItem`